# Haxe: Import from neko, cpp and java sys trees

Tags: package, haxe, nme, neko, multi-targeting

I want to use Haxe to write a library that can be used by other projects in various different languages.

Currently I have at the top of my library:

```
import neko.io.File;
import neko.io.FileInput;
import neko.io.FileOutput;
import neko.FileSystem;
import neko.io.Process;
```

So my library compiles to neko just fine, using the `-neko` flag.  However if I try to use the `-cpp` flag, the packages cannot be found:

```
$ haxe -cp src -main sws/Root.hx -cpp build/sws.CXX
src/sws/Root.hx:3: characters 0-20 : You can't access the neko package with current compilation flags (for neko.io.File)
```

I thought the solution would be to instead do the imports like this:

```
import sys.io.File;
import sys.io.FileInput;
import sys.io.FileOutput;
import sys.FileSystem;
import sys.io.Process;
```

and let Haxe change `sys` into `neko` or `cpp` depending on the compile flag I use.  (Assuming all the modules are available in all the target languages.)  But that doesn't work either.

```
$ haxe -cp src -main sws/Root.hx -neko build/sws.n
src/sws/Root.hx:3: characters 0-19 : Class not found : sys.io.File
$ haxe -cp src -main sws/Root.hx -cpp build/sws.CXX
src/sws/Root.hx:3: characters 0-19 : Class not found : sys.io.File
```

How should I be doing it?

Comment: What is your compilation line(s) ? sys.io.File works fine on cpp and neko

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  I have added my compile lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `import neko.io.File;` works, you're probably using Haxe 2.x, not Haxe 3.  (Unless I'm missing something?)

In Haxe 3, you would use `import sys.io.File` etc.  Migration notes for Haxe 3 can be found at: http://haxe.org/manual/haxe3/migration

In Haxe 2, you had to do it per target.  I would do things like:

```
#if neko
    import neko.io.File;
    import neko.io.FileInput;
    import neko.io.FileOutput;
    import neko.FileSystem;
    import neko.io.Process;
#elseif cpp
    import cpp.io.File;
    import cpp.io.FileInput;
    import cpp.io.FileOutput;
    import cpp.FileSystem;
    import cpp.io.Process;
#end
```

Assuming of course all those classes existed in the CPP target on your Haxe release.

If not, maybe look at upgrading to Haxe 3 :)

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation.  I think I will take the upgrade to Haxe 3 route!

Comment: The link to haxe manual is dead.  Try http://old.haxe.org/manual/haxe3/migration instead.